# How can I override the styling of multiple IDs with just one class?

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-selectors

A part of my webpage is built to look like 3 lights with inner gleams to give them some depth. The html for these lights looks like this:

```html
<div id="redLightOuter" class="outer">
  <div id="redLightInner" class="inner">
  </div>
</div>
<div id="yellowLightOuter" class="outer">
  <div id="yellowLightInner" class="inner">
  </div>
</div>
<div id="greenLightOuter" class="outer">
  <div id="greenLightInner" class="inner">
  </div>
</div>
```

When the user presses a "power" button, these lights and their inner gleams are supposed to go grey but the only way I've found to override the specificity of these div's styling is with this CSS:

```css
div#redLightInner.lightsOff {
  background-color: var(--inner-grey);
}
div#yellowLightInner.lightsOff {
  background-color: var(--inner-grey);
}
div#greenLightInner.lightsOff {
  background-color: var(--inner-grey);
}
div#redLightOuter.lightsOff {
  background-color: var(--outer-grey);
}
div#yellowLightOuter.lightsOff {
  background-color: var(--outer-grey);
}
div#greenLightOuter.lightsOff {
  background-color: var(--outer-grey);
}
```

Which is toggled on and off with this function linked to my power button.

```js
function power() {
  document.getElementById("redLightInner").classList.toggle("lightsOff");
  document.getElementById("yellowLightInner").classList.toggle("lightsOff");
  document.getElementById("redLightOuter").classList.toggle("lightsOff");
  document.getElementById("yellowLightOuter").classList.toggle("lightsOff");
  document.getElementById("greenLightOuter").classList.toggle("lightsOff");
  document.getElementById("greenLightInner").classList.toggle("lightsOff");
}
```

Is there any way to do this more elegantly and with less code?

Comment: `.querySelectorAll()` + `NodeList.prototype.forEach()` or a `for` loop

Answer (score 0):

The code can be shorter (and more flexible) by toggling the class on a parent element (or even the `body` itself) and use `.inner` and `.outer` classes.

```css
body.lightsOff .inner,
body.lightsOff .outer {
  background-color: var(--inner-grey)
}
```

Note that it might not work because the "regular" mode style are in higher [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) so you might modify the `.lightsOff` selector as well.